# Question about using beautifulsoup to parse html

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I just got started out learning to use BeautifulSoup in Python to parse html and have a very simple stupid question. Somehow, I just couldn't get Text 1 only from the html below (stored in containers).

```
....
<div class="listA">
<span><span>Text 1</span><b>Text 2</b><b>Text 3</b></span>
</div>
...
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "listA"})
datas = []
for data in containers:
    textspan = data.find("span")
    datas.append(textspan.text)
```

The output is as follows: `Text1Text2Text3`

Any advice how to delimit them as well? Thanks and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want *Text 1* use this code

```
import bs4

content = "<span><span>Text 1</span><b>Text 2</b><b>Text 3</b></span>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')


# soup('span') will give you
# [<span><span>Text 1</span><b>Text 2</b><b>Text 3</b></span>, <span>Text 1</span>]

span_text = soup('span')

for e in span_text:
    if not e('span'):
        print(e.text)
```

Output:

```
Text 1
```

Comment: Thank you! But there are multiple instances of the span text (without the ones in <b>) that I want to retrieve, hence the for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks much, works! However I need to use soup to parse the div portion of the code with the class attribute. I have modified the code above, if you would have any advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution involves simplifieddoc, which does not rely on third-party libraries and is lighter and faster, perfect for beginners.
Here are more examples [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
<span><span>Text 1</span><b>Text 2</b><b>Text 3</b></span>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
span = doc.span # Get the outermost span
first = span.span # Get the first span in span
print (first.text)
second = span.b
print (second.text)
third = second.next
print (third.text)
```

Result:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```